# Change vignette handling?

Tags: rstudio, knitr, sweave

I'd like to write a vignette in Sweave or knitr and edit it in the RStudio IDE, but I don't want to use the standard code to weave it, I'd like some pre-preprocessing (with my patchDVI package).  Is there a way to replace the code that does the .Rnw to .tex translation?

One idea I thought of for this was to create a new non-Sweave vignette engine, and declare it in the document (using %\VignetteEngine), but RStudio ignores the declaration, and just runs the regular Sweave() function, which fails.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to customize the weaving code in RStudio.

The best thing I can think of is to put your own weaving code in a Makefile, place the RStudio IDE and your PDF viewer side by side. Then use something like a shell script to compile the vignette, e.g.

```
while true;
  do sleep 1 && make vignette;
done
```

A sample Makefile:

```
vignette: foo.pdf

%.pdf: %.Rnw
    your_own_command && R CMD Sweave $<
```